# Naming a Flutter Plugin EventChannel

Tags: flutter, flutter-plugin, flutter-platform-channel

I created a new plugin with

```
flutter create --template plugin alfalfa
```

which generates `lib/alfalfa.dart` containing

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class Alfalfa {
  static const MethodChannel _channel =
      const MethodChannel('alfalfa');

  //...
}
```

I want to add an `EventChannel` so Java and Objective-C code can call back to the Dart code. I don't know what the name of the `EventChannel` should be.

```
final EventChannel _eventChannel =
    const EventChannel("com.rollingfields.alfalfa/events");
```

or

```
final EventChannel _eventChannel =
    const EventChannel("alfalfa/events");
```

or something else? Is there a convention?

If the better option for the `EventChannel` is the name including the reverse domain, should I rename the generated `MethodChannel` to be `com.rollingfields.alfalfa`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When in doubt, check the flutter plugins repo. The connectivity plugin uses:

```
  @visibleForTesting
  static const MethodChannel methodChannel = MethodChannel(
    'plugins.flutter.io/connectivity',
  );

  @visibleForTesting
  static const EventChannel eventChannel = EventChannel(
    'plugins.flutter.io/connectivity_status',
  );
```

so, certainly one example of good practice. So, perhaps `com.rollingfields/alfalfa` and `com.rollingfields/alfalfa_events`

Comment: Thank you, Richard! (How strange they didn't use the standard reverse domain name convention for namespacing.)